# WPF: Cannot create an instance of all control in a user control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I use custom control in my WPF application. This custom control includes logic and resource dictionary. 
In my application I have login window and main window. Application first loads login window

```
<Application x:Class="Dest.App"
             ....
             StartupUri="Login.xaml">
</Application>
```

Custom control I use in my main window

```
<time:Calendar CloseAppointment="OnDeleteAppointment" AddAppointment="OnAddAppointment" Appointments="{Binding Path=Model}" />
```

Also in MainWindow I load resource dictionary from assembly

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCalendar;component/Dictionary.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Visual Studio loads custom control without any exceptions. But when I load application and successfully login, viewmodel of the login view calls main windows

```
 MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
 mainWindow.Show();
```

Constructor of the main window

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();    
   m_MainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
   this.DataContext = m_MainViewModel;
}
```

I receive an exception

[Exception](http://oi48.tinypic.com/11ljskh.jpg)

Exception details

> at WpfCalendar.Logic.Calendar.FilterAppointments() in
>   D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\LotusScheduler\WpfScheduler\WpfCalendar\Logic\Calendar.cs:line
>   122 at
>   WpfCalendar.Logic.Calendar.OnAppointmentsChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) in D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\LotusScheduler\WpfScheduler\WpfCalendar\Logic\Calendar.cs:line
>   109 at
>   WpfCalendar.Logic.Calendar.OnAppointmentsChanged(DependencyObject d,
>   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\LotusScheduler\WpfScheduler\WpfCalendar\Logic\Calendar.cs:line
>   100 at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType) at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue,
>   Boolean isASubPropertyChange) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt
>   attempt) at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean
>   lastChance) at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean
>   lastChance) at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg) at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent() at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
>   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget) at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget) at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(ICompositionTarget
>   resizedCompositionTarget) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef
>   hWndInsertAfter, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 cx, Int32 cy, Int32 flags) at
>   System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double
>   requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight) at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow) at
>   System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow() at
>   System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow() at
>   System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox) at
>   System.Windows.Window.Show() at
>   ViewModel.LoginingViewModel.Login(Object parameter) in
>   D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\Lotus\AMS\Dentist\ViewModel\LoginingViewModel.cs:line 162 at
>   ViewModel.LoginingViewModel.b__0(Object param) in
>   D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\Lotus\AMS\Dentist\ViewModel\LoginingViewModel.cs:line 115 at
>   ViewModel.CommonCommand.Execute(Object parameter) in
>   D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\Lotus\AMS\Dentist\Commands\CommonCommand.cs:line 59 at
>   MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource
>   commandSource, Boolean userInitiated) at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick() at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick() at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e) at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget) at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target) at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised) at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent) at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget) at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target) at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised) at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args) at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args) at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   trusted) at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled) at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled) at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs) at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore) at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window) at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window) at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run() at Dentist.App.Main() in
>   D:\development\Dental
>   Soft\Lotus\AMS\Dentist\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0 at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args) at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Part of the resource dictionary with problem controls

```
<Border BorderBrush="#A5BFE1" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" Background="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
    <TextBlock x:Name="DayHeader" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.CalendarSelectedDayTitle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.CalendarSelectedDayDescription}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
</Border>
<time:Scroll x:Name="scrollViewer" CustomVerticalOffset="640.0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <time:TimeRibbon Grid.Column="0"></time:TimeRibbon>
        <time:SchedulerDay Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Day"></time:SchedulerDay>
    </Grid>
</time:Scroll>
```

Constructor of the Calendar control (that throw exception)

```
public Calendar()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Calendar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Calendar)));

    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Calendar), 
        new CommandBinding(NextDay, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(OnExecutedNextDay), 
            new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(OnCanExecuteNextDay)));

    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Calendar),
        new CommandBinding(PreviousDay, new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(OnExecutedPreviousDay),
            new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(OnCanExecutePreviousDay)));
}
```

But when set in app.xaml the first window MainWindow, not LoginWindow everything works properly without any excetions!

Please advise what can be cause of the problem?

Thank you

Comment: You've got everything in here except *the exact information we need to help you* -- the exception details.  Re-run, then click the link highlighted here http://i.stack.imgur.com/JDnyI.png then [edit] and add it to your question.

Comment: Exception details is a really huge....

Comment: Exception details tell us 1) where the exception occurred 2) what inner exceptions there are. Without that, your question is pointless.  You could throw 90% of this question away and supply the exception details and get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is ocurring (as per your screenshot) in your FilterAppointments class constructor. In which you're performing some actions based on your controltemplate, but the template is not yet assigned in that moment. You should override OnApplyTemplate() and move that code there instead.

Comment: I have a DependencyProperty 'Appointments'. This property has an event handler that calls FilterAppointments method. I think the reason of the exception that not all controls of the custom control was initialized in time. But I cannot understand how it's connected with first loaded windows - if login windows (without custom control) is loaded first and then main is loaded (with custom control) I have an exception. If I load main window first everything is OK.

Comment: Again, the Dependency Property change callback is being called BEFORE the control template is applied, that's why your GetTemplateChild() returns null. just check the value is not null before doing the rest of the method. not rocket science

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you a lot for your help!  
In FilterAppointments methods I have added checking if my objects not null and override OnApplyTemplate(). In OnApplyTemplate() I simply call FilterAppointments.  

Thank you again!